# AngularJS-Slick is not working even after including all necessary scripts in proper order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

I am making use of an angularJs-slick slider for my project to show some packages as a sliding feature.

I have included all the necessary files and dynamically getting packages via the controller.

Here the package is showing one after the other instead of in slider with the slide controller buttons. and the control buttons are not loaded into the DOM. any help appreciated. correct me if am doing anything wrong here. thank you

````
    <div class="row slick-container">
            <slick settings="responsiveConfig">
                {% verbatim %}
                    <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-0-5 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-0-5">
                        <div class="row slick-container text-elegant">
                            <slick slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="4">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 space-bottom-none slick-anchor space-top-none" ng-repeat="item in popularpackages">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-elegant">
                                        <div class="panel-header text-center hidden-xs">
                                            <img class="img-responsive inline full-block" ng-src="/images/aa1.{{loop.index+1}}.jpg" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <a ng-click="trackPopularClick('{{item.test_name}}')" title="{{ item.test_name }}">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <div title="{{ item.test_name }}">
                                                        <h3 class="space-top-none text-heading text-primary text-ellipsis text-center">{{ item.test_name }}</h3>
                                                        <span class="text-sm text-muted">Best Suited Category:</span>
                                                        <img class="img-responsive inline"  style="height:1em;display:inline;border:0;" ng-src="/images/{{ item.item_icon }}.png"> <span class="text-sm text-muted">{{ item.item_name }}</span>
                                                        <div class="text-elegant text-heading text-muted text-center space-top-lg">
                                                            <span class="text-base text-center">{{ item.bundledTestsCount }} parameters</span></br>
                                                            <span>
                                                                INR
                                                                <del class="text-muted">{{ item.price }}</del>
                                                                <span class="text-secondary text-lg">{{ item.displayPrice }}</span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <hr />
                                                        <span ng-repeat="organ in item.organCovered | split:',':0">
                                                            <img title="{{ organ }}" alt="{{ organ }}"
                                                                    class="inline img-responsive" ng-src="/images/organs/{{ organ|trim }}.png"
                                                                    style="height: 15px;">
                                                            <span class="text-primary">{{ organ|trim }}</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                        </br></br>
                                                        <a href="/packages/{{item.slug}}-in-{{locationCity}}">
                                                        <button class="btn-span blueBorderBtn btn-float-left">+ Know more</button>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-float-right" ng-click="checkout(item.testLabId,locationCityId)">Book Now</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </slick>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                {% endverbatim %}
            </slick>
        </div>

verbatims are used because I am using twig 
```JAVASCRIPTS: this is in the proper structure 
    angular.module('MT.app', [
        'slickCarousel'
    ])

    .controller ('popularTestsController', function (
            $scope,
        ) {
        $scope.responsiveConfig = {
            enabled: true,
            autoplay: true,
            draggable: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 3000,
            method: {},
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            event: {
                beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                },
                afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                }
            },
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }]
        };

    })

javascript is properly included in the js file, from module declaration to controller usage.
below css and JS cdn are included in the same order as I have mentioned below:
```CSS CDN 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"/>

```JS CDN 
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-slick-carousel/3.1.7/angular-slick.js"></script>
````

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: no errors :-( @MasterPo

Comment: Try adding the slick library script tag after the body tag

Comment: added but there is nothing and no errors @AkberIqbal

Comment: Angular-slick works fine with hardcoded but when we include the ng-repeater then it doesn't. if you are making a mockup please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-if for the slick to load

```
<slick setting="responsiveConfig" arrows="true" ng-if="popularpackages.length > 0">
```